# Karma coverage with files and tests in same location

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am setting up karma in an existing project. I have it working and running the tests properly, but I cannot seem to get coverage working.

I have all the necessary modules installed, but I think it has to do with how I include my files in the "preprocessors" object.

My project is setup with the file structure below

```
App
|--js
  |-- fileToTest.js
  |-- fileToTest.Tests.js
```

In the karma coverage docs it says not to include tests or libraries when setting up coverage. I guess I'm wondering how to exclude the files with ".Tests.js" at the end.

My preprocessors object looks like below. Is there a way to include the files I want to generate coverage for using a glob, or will I unfortunately have to individually add those files?

```
preprocessors: {
    './App/**/*.tpl.html' : 'ng-html2js',
    './App/**/*.js': ['coverage']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karma use https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch to find the files (it's mention here http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/preprocessors.html) so you can use a glob.

On our project we just add our code from various folders, it was not that bad :

```
preprocessors: {
          // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
          // do not include tests or libraries
          // (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
          'www/js/controllers/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
          'www/js/directives/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
          'www/js/filters/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
          'www/js/initializers/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
          'www/js/services/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
          'www/js/services.js': ['coverage']
    }
```

**EDIT  :**

Reffering to this https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/508

It seems that this syntax is working

```
resources/javascript/**/!(*Spec).js
```

Apply to you it would be

```
'./App/**/!(*Tests).js': ['coverage']
```

Comment: I don't think that would work. Taking my example into account, the glob pattern you have above would match both the test files and the actual files, where the test files are not supposed to be included